# is it possible to compile c++ class template instances?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Suppose that I write a class template, say `Vector<typename T>`. I want to expose `using fvec = Vector<float>;` and `using dvec = Vector<double>;` to my clients.

Ideally, I do not want my clients know how the template `Vector` is implemented, or better, they need only know the existence of `fvec` and `dvec` and a pre-compiled file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, Vector is just a name for anything, reinventing `std::vector` is beyond my interest.

Comment: you would have to use your template as an implementation class I guess.

Comment: See the bottom of Luc's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Only if you implement each type explicitly in the .cpp file, rather than implementing them generically in the header.

Comment: You want a typedef not a using statement:

    typedef Vector<float> fvec;
    typedef Vector<double> dvec;

Comment: check my answer, but here is one more crazy idea - two decorator clases with pimpl :) I often use this for old C libraries, when I call them from C++.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deliver the clients just header file and implementation just for double and float, you can explicit instantiate the template class into cpp file.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template

e.g. you need something like this in cpp file

```
 template class Vector<float>;
 template class Vector<double>;
```

For easy usage, you can also do some typedefs in h file - this is because someone might decide to use it with "quadruple" type (libquadmath)

Alternatively you can create tho more clases into h file that inherits from the template, but this is same as typedefs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program that builds and runs. The implementation of the class template `Foo` is hidden in Foo.cc.

Foo.h

```
#pragma once

template <typename T> class Foo
{
   public:

      Foo();

      void test();
};

template class Foo<float>;
template class Foo<int>;
```

Foo.cc

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo()
{
}

template <typename T> void Foo<T>::test()
{
   std::cout << "Came to Foo<T>::test\n";
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
   Foo<int> f1;
   f1.test();

   Foo<float> f2;
   f2.test();

   // Uncommenting these lines results in linker error.
   // Foo<double> f3;
   // f3.test();
}
```

Command to build:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 Foo.cc main.cc -o program
```

I am also able to build using:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c Foo.cc
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c main.cc
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 Foo.o main.o -o program
```

You can ship Foo.h and a library that contains Foo.o. Your clients will be limited to using `Foo<int>` and `Foo<float>`.

Comment: template class Foo<float>;
template class Foo<int>;
Those can be in .cc file as well.

Comment: @Nick, that too will work. I still prefer to have them in the .h file since it expresses the intent better -- that `Foo` can be used with `int` and `float` and nothing else.